# MongoDB cache or memory leak when use aggregation

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a trouble with mongodb usage too many memory, and not free it after a request (I think is cache but can not find anything that can help me ).I use python Flask and Mongodb in my project, after initial app memory usage ~35kb
[before request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeeS7.png) after aggregation ~598mb [after request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo1j2.png)
aggregation looks like this

```
    aggregate_exp = [
    {
        '$match': {
            '{}'.format(pattern): {'$regex': value, '$options': 'i'}
        }
    },
    {
        '$limit': 200
    },
    {
        '$project': {
            '_id': False,
            'value': '${}'.format(pattern)
        }
    },
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$value'
        }
    },
]
```

thanks for answers, I hope you help me

Comment: With find, I had the same problem, I know it problem with indexes, but why mongodb not free this memory after request?

Comment: That's not a leak, it's the cache. MongoDB keeps most recently used data in RAM. So if you have created indexes for your queries and your working data set fits in RAM, MongoDB serves all queries from memory.